# Reading a .ipynb file from a shared folder

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, conda

I created a simple bash script to automatically read a certain file path in a shared folder where I store some of my notebooks:

```
set root=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
call %root%\Scripts\activate.bat
call pushd \\<remote machine in the network>\file
call jupyter notebook --browser "C:/Home/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"
```

The `set root` activates the `activate.bat` so it works like a Anaconda Prompt and `pushd` creates a virtual mapped directory to my shared folder. `jupyter notebook` is ran with the `--browser` parameter where my Google Chrome is sitting.

I am returned with the error:

```
[W 19:05:55.438 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser
```

Which I understand that `jupyter` was not successful in finding the browser path that I defined. What is weird is, if I run the file line by line in `cmd.exe`, it works fine and launches Chrome with Jupyter.

I am relying on bash so that I can share this simple setup with users in a team that can refer to the same source files with standardize file paths. I know there is Jupyter Notebook Server for this kind of stuff but think it will be overkill just for notebook sharing.

Comment: Will it be overkill if several people modify the same notebook at the same time though? And by the way, I can't find any doc on the `--browser` option, could you point out where you found it?

Comment: Not really, the team is small, at the moment, maybe only me and another person. I found the `--browser` option from `jupyter notebook --help`, which can also be found [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html).